# Restrict home directory from showing all the accounts

Tags: php, apache, centos7

When I run the following code in one of the website on my CentOS 7 box.

```
$directories = glob($somePath . '/home/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
var_dump( $directories );
```

The code above list all the accounts that's in the server.

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "/home/example1"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "/home/example2"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "/home/example3"
}
```

How can I restrict that ONLY the account where the website is hosted is listed. In my case `/home/example2` should be listed ONLY.

Comment: This is called chroot. This isn’t a place to ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your use case for this, but this function will get you back directories that contain the website you're currently viewing.

```
function filter(){
    $directories = glob($somePath . '/home/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($directories as $key=>$value){
        if(!stristr(__FILE__, $value)){
            unset($directories[$key];
        }
    }
    return $directories;
}
```